# Where can I find an iPhone 4S skin image?

Tags: iphone, graphics

We need to build a static web page with an iPhone on it containing animated views to showcase our app. To start with we need an iPhone 4S skin, better to be a white one to hold the rest of images, so I was wondering where can we find such skin. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By snooping around in the iPhone simulator app bundle, i came up with this in
`/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/Applications/iPhone Simulator.app/Contents/Resources/`:

[image]

It's higher quality, already has the middle (screen area) cleared out, and the aforementioned folder even includes a sprite for the pressed home button

Answer (score 2):

I got one by launching the iOS simulator from Xcode and taking a screenshot:

[image: iPhone simulator]